# Variable concatenated mysql query string runs fine in phpMyAdmin but not PHP in script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, syntax-error

UPDATED 14/04/2011

Still in trouble. I reduced my code to its simplest form. I use the IF function to check isset() for a checkbox, which works fine. If the checkbox is checked it concatenates a string made of two parts. Very simple.

```
if (isset($_POST[testType1])) {
   $filterQuery .= "(testType1 = '1'"; 
   }
   $filterQuery .= ") ";
}
```

When I use mysql_fetch_assoc and echo the info in the $rows it works. But when I view the page source it in Google Chrome it says:

`Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`;

If I echo $filterQuery it displays correctly and when I copy the echoed string into my code MySQL returns the correct results:

`SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE (testType1 = '1')`

I have tried casting $filterQuery to a string as well. No success.

UPDATED 12/04/2011

I still have a problem, it wasn't a typo. See code below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE ";`
$orTrigger = "";`

function setOrTrigger() {
    global $orTrigger;
    if ($orTrigger=="") {
        $orTrigger="OR ";
    }
}

function getTestFilterQuery($testType) {
   if (!(isset($_POST[test1])) && !(isset($_POST[test2])) && !(isset($_POST[test3]))) {
     $returnString = NULL;
     return $returnString;
   }

}

if (isset($_POST[testType1])) {
   $filterQuery .= $orTrigger ."(testType1 = '1'"; 
   setOrTrigger();
   $addTestFilterQuery = getTestFilterQuery("testType1");
   if ($addTestFilterQuery != NULL) {
    $filterQuery .= "AND " .$addTestFilterQuery;
   }
   $filterQuery .= ") ";
}

$connection = mysql_connect(localhost, $username, $password);

if (!$connection) {
   die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());

}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

$result = mysql_query($filterQuery);

if (!$result) {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $row['name'];
   echo $row['description'];
}
```

When I echo $query I get:

`SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE (testType1 = '1')`

When I copy this directly into mysql_query like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE (testType1 = '1')");
```

it works fine. But when I pass the variable like:

mysql_query($filterQuery);

i get a syntax error one near ''. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: What error do you get? Maybe show us your code?

Comment: Can you give a code example of a fixed variable eg $tmp = 'myname' and  the select and how you're inserting the variable into the query

Comment: You should probably post your code.  Otherwise, we are blind.

Comment: `The variable sql statement starts with "SELECT FROM... and ends with "` yeah, it's cool. But we want some real code.

Comment: its like guessing in a blackout .. but I am guessing  the answer to be "backticks"

Comment: Best I can suggest is to do a var_dump/strlen on the generated query string and see if the actual length matches what you see in there. Possibly there's a hidden control character of some sort throwing off the query.

Comment: var_dump returns:

`string 'SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE (testType1 = '1') ' (length=86)`

Not sure if the single quotes inside the single quotes could be a problem, but I have tried using real escape with errors at "\'". Will check again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually putting the double quotes in the string, like:

```
$query = '"SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value"';
echo $query; //output is exactly: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value"
```

If so, you need to remove the `"`s from inside the string, mysql_query or whatever takes a normal string like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value";
echo $query; //output is exactly: SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value
```

In much the same way, you don't end an SQL query with `;` in the string like: `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = value;";`

Comment: +1 for the "don't end with ;" hint. mysql_query doesn't support multi-querying

Comment: @Giacomo: more like the underlying driver doesn't. mysql_query() just passes the query string directly onwards, it couldn't care less if there's invalid syntax, one query, or 500 queries in there.

Comment: @Marc: I was just discussing the effect, from the point of view of the client, no matter the implementation. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

example of concat for query

```
$query = "select * from tablename ";
$query.= "WHERE id=1";
$query.= " and item_id= 'foo'";
```

Comment: `code` SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE (acc1 = '1')

Comment: Sorry about that comment, new to this site. The concat part is fine, works like a charm, when I echo $query I get: `SELECT * FROM fdatav1 JOIN ddatav1 ON ddatav1.ID = fdatav1.ID WHERE (acc1 = '1')` which works in phpmyadmin but, putting it in `$result = mysql_query($query)` I get a syntax error near ''

Comment: try this: WHERE (\`acc1` = '1' )

Comment: @Stewie: backticks are only required when the field/table name are a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an else block to this bit of the code, as per below. otherwise $filterQuery will never get set unless isset($_POST[testType1]).

```
if (isset($_POST[testType1])) {
   $filterQuery .= $orTrigger ."(testType1 = '1'"; 
   setOrTrigger();
   $addTestFilterQuery = getTestFilterQuery("testType1");
   if ($addTestFilterQuery != NULL) {
    $filterQuery .= "AND " .$addTestFilterQuery;
   }
   $filterQuery .= ") ";
} else {
   $filterQuery = $query;
}
```